# No value returned when using identity() in the within step, but values are returned when hardcoded

Tags: gremlin

I'm new to gremlin. 
Here's a sample graph

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<graphml xmlns='http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns'>
    <key id='labelV'  for='node' attr.name='labelV'  attr.type='string'></key>
    <key id='type'    for='node' attr.name='type'    attr.type='string'></key>
    <key id='pick'    for='node' attr.name='pick'    attr.type='string'></key>
    <key id='match'   for='node' attr.name='match'   attr.type='string'></key>
    <key id='pot'  for='node' attr.name='pot'  attr.type='double'></key>
    <key id='stake'   for='node' attr.name='stake'   attr.type='double'></key>
    <key id='labelE'  for='edge' attr.name='labelE'  attr.type='string'></key>

<graph id='routes' edgedefault='directed'>
    <!-- vertices -->
    <node id='1'>
        <data key='labelV'>transaction</data>
        <data key='type'>transaction</data>
        <data key='match'>M1</data>
        <data key='pos'>H1</data>
        <data key='pick'>M1H1</data>
        <data key='pot'>100.0</data>
        <data key='stake'>10.0</data>
    </node>
    <node id='2'>
        <data key='labelV'>transaction</data>
        <data key='type'>transaction</data>
        <data key='match'>M1</data>
        <data key='pos'>D1</data>
        <data key='pick'>M1D1</data>
        <data key='pot'>50.0</data>
        <data key='stake'>5.0</data>
    </node>
    <node id='3'>
        <data key='labelV'>transaction</data>
        <data key='type'>transaction</data>
        <data key='match'>M1</data>
        <data key='pos'>A1</data>
        <data key='pick'>M1A1</data>
        <data key='pot'>150.0</data>
        <data key='stake'>15.0</data>
    </node>
    <node id='4'>
        <data key='labelV'>transaction</data>
        <data key='type'>transaction</data>
        <data key='match'>M2</data>
        <data key='pos'>A2</data>
        <data key='pick'>M2A2</data>
        <data key='pot'>75.0</data>
        <data key='stake'>10.0</data>
    </node>
    <node id='5'>
        <data key='labelV'>transaction</data>
        <data key='type'>transaction</data>
        <data key='match'>M3</data>
        <data key='pos'>A3</data>
        <data key='pick'>M3A3</data>
        <data key='pot'>70.0</data>
        <data key='stake'>7.0</data>
    </node>
    <node id='6'>
        <data key='labelV'>transaction</data>
        <data key='type'>transaction</data>
        <data key='match'>M1</data>
        <data key='pos'>H1</data>
        <data key='pick'>M1H1:M2D2</data>
        <data key='pot'>60.0</data>
        <data key='stake'>6.0</data>
    </node>

    <!-- edges -->
    <edge id='20' source='1' target='4'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='21' source='1' target='5'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='22' source='1' target='6'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='23' source='2' target='4'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='24' source='2' target='5'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='25' source='3' target='4'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='26' source='3' target='5'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='27' source='4' target='1'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='28' source='4' target='2'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='29' source='4' target='3'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='30' source='4' target='5'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='31' source='5' target='1'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='32' source='5' target='2'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='33' source='5' target='3'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='34' source='5' target='4'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='35' source='5' target='6'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='36' source='6' target='1'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id='37' source='6' target='5'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
    </edge>
</graph>
</graphml>
```

I can't figure out how to add a property with with multiple values with graphML, so here's the code to add an additional value to V(6)

```
g.V(6).property(set, 'match', "M2")
```

The goal is to calculate the maximum `pot` in the graph by getting each node and its connected vertices, grouping the vertices of that node, by their match values ( grouping two nodes means they have at least one intersecting `match` value), taking the maximum of each group, and doing the sum for that node. At the end, with take the maximum value of all the nodes. I don't know if this is quite how it should be done but this is what I've tried:

```
g.E().hasLabel('compatible').outV().dedup().as('s').   //1. get all edges with comptible label
local(                                                 //2. for each node
    union(                                             //3. get the node and its first level connected vertices
        identity(),
        out()
    )
    .as('compat')
    .values('match')                                  //4. get the values of the match property

    .as('match')
    .local(                                           //5. for each key in the list
        select('compat')                              //6. get all vertices in the sub graph that have this value in their match list
        .has('match',within(identity()))              //7
        .order().by("pot", decr).limit(1)             //8. get the one with the highest pot value

    )
    .dedup()                                          //9. remove duplicates
    .values('pot')
    .sum()                                            //10. sum the values for this node
).max()                                               //11. get the max for all nodes
```

EXPECTED RESULT:
For each vertex, we should have its BulkSet as follows:

```
V(5)==>[M1:[v[2],v[3],v[6],v[1]],M2:[v[4],v[6]],M3:[v[5]]]
V(6)==>[M1:[v[6],v[1]],M3:[v[5]]]
V(1)==>[M1:[v[1],v[6]],M2:[v[4], v[6]],M3:[v[5]]]
V(2)==>[M1:[v[2]],M2:[v[4]],M3:[v[5]]]
V(3)==>[M1:[v[3]],M2:[v[4]],M3:[v[5]]]
V(4)==>[M1:[v[1],v[2],v[3]],M2:[v[4]],M3:[v[5]]]
```

and the map of the maximum `pot`s of each vertex:

```
V(5) ==> [M1:v[3],M2:v[4],M3:v[5]],     Sum(pot) ==> 150 + 75 + 70 = 295
V(6) ==> [M1:v[1],M3:v[5]],             Sum(pot) ==> 100 + 70      = 170
V(1) ==> [M1:v[1],M2:[v[4]],M3:v[5]],   Sum(pot) ==> 100 + 75 + 70 = 295
V(2) ==> [M1:v[2],M2:v[4],M3:v[5]],     Sum(pot) ==> 50  + 75 + 70 = 195
V(3) ==> [M1:v[3],M2:v[4],M3:v[5]],     Sum(pot) ==> 150 + 75 + 70 = 295
V(4) ==> [M1:v[3],M2:v[4],M3:v[5]],     Sum(pot) ==> 150 + 75 + 70 = 295
```

The final output should be 295.

The first problem is at 7. If I pass static values such as `['M1', 'M2']` I do get data but get an empty list with `identity()`.

The second problem is at 8. I get multiple nodes instead of just the node with the maximum value.

Comment: In the first part of your expected result, why is `M2` not part of the `v[6]`'s bulkset?

Comment: You are right. Actually it should. I will update it and post a follow up under your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your expected result is not quite right (`M2` should be part of v[6]'s bulkset). That said, here's what I think the solution looks like:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("transaction").
           map(union(identity(), out("compatible")).as("v").
           values("match").
           group().
             by().
             by(select("v").order().by("pot", decr)))
==>[M1:v[1],M2:v[4],M3:v[5]]
==>[M1:v[2],M2:v[4],M3:v[5]]
==>[M1:v[3],M2:v[4],M3:v[5]]
==>[M1:v[3],M2:v[4],M3:v[5]]
==>[M1:v[3],M2:v[4],M3:v[5]]
==>[M1:v[1],M2:v[6],M3:v[5]]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("transaction").
           map(union(identity(), out("compatible")).as("v").
           values("match").
           group().
             by().
             by(select("v").order().by("pot", decr))).
           map(select(values).unfold().values("pot").fold())
==>[100.0,75.0,70.0]
==>[50.0,75.0,70.0]
==>[150.0,75.0,70.0]
==>[150.0,75.0,70.0]
==>[150.0,75.0,70.0]
==>[100.0,60.0,70.0]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("transaction").
           map(union(identity(), out("compatible")).as("v").
           values("match").
           group().
             by().
             by(select("v").order().by("pot", decr))).
           map(select(values).unfold().values("pot").sum()).
           max()
==>295.0
```

Comment: I did not include M2 as part of v[6]'s bulkset because I want have a group for a multiple `match` node only if there is another node with the same `match`. An example is `v[1]` which has the same `match` `M1` as `v[6]`. Having it duplicated in different groups now makes the bulkset's value larger than it should in the case where two groups return the same node.

Comment: I don't get it. Why is M3 included then?

Comment: Because of the edge  
  
`<edge id='37' source='6' target='5'>
        <data key='labelE'>compatible</data>
 </edge>`  
  
If there is an edge between them, then there should be a group for that.

Comment: I don't think the expected result you've posted follows your rules. For example, in your `v[5]` bulkset you have `M3: v[5]`, even though `v[5]` is the only vertex with a match value of `M3`. So that breaks the rule that you mentioned above: ... only if there is another node with the same `match`. Or does that only apply to multi-valued `match` properties?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that. It only applies to nodes  multi-valued `match`properties nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me on the example above:

```
g.V().hasLabel('transaction').local(
union(identity(), out('compatible')).as('v')
    .values('match')
    .group()
    .by()
    .by(select('v').values('pot').max()).select(values).unfold().sum()
).max()
```

Comment: @naomi621  I tried using groupby before. The problem with `group().by(values('match'))` is that it groups only using the first value of the property. For example, in the sub-graph of V(5), V(6) is supposed to be grouped both in M1 and M2, but in this case, if M1 is the first element in the set, then it only gets grouped with other M1 nodes.

Comment: I fixed it, I still think this solution is slightly better than the one suggested by Daniel. using 'max' as a reducer should be more efficient than 'order by'. @theking